# MySQL Alias Column Wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, select, wildcard

We search for the possibility to use wildcards in a mysql SELECT Statement **inside the Collumn alias**

like this:

For each column:

```
SELECT a.* as task_*, b.* as types_* 
FROM tasks AS a 
LEFT JOIN types AS b 
ON a.type_id = b.id_type 
ORDER BY a.lastmod DESC
```

Not only for explicit columns:

```
SELECT a.title as task_title, b.title as types_title 
FROM tasks AS a 
LEFT JOIN types AS b 
ON a.type_id = b.id_type 
ORDER BY a.lastmod DESC
```

but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Note: as prefix for collumn names short hand

```
a.* as prefix_*
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you give an example of expected input and output?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can only assign an alias for a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to explicitly select each column and assign alias names for each column

```
example: select a.emp_name as task_empame, a.location as task_location from ...
```

Comment: maybe a feature request for mysql dev - no any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT a.* as task_` is completely wrong. Column alias are for single column and not for entire column list. With `*` operator you are selecting all columns from your respective table. You need to modify your query like

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tasks AS a 
LEFT JOIN types AS b 
ON a.type_id = b.id_type 
ORDER BY a.lastmod DESC
```

(OR) explicitly set column alias for each column in select list. Per your comment, `a.* as prefix_(*)` can't be done since that type of construct is not built into.

Comment: thats not what i want! - Stackoverflow has some problems with the second wildcard *

i want : SELECT a.* as task_(*)

Comment: you mean `a.* as prefix_*`. No that type of construct is not present and so can't be done.